# Unix time/ epoch time: Date representation or time block?

Tags: java, mysql, unix-timestamp, epoch

I've recently taken over some responsibility of a database, and one of the fields is "time worked". This is represented as a VARCHAR in MySQL and is in the form:

'1970-01-01 00:05:46' (example)
All entries start with 1970-01-01 hh:MM:ss and have the same format.

I'm trying to figure out if this represents simply a date and time in a day, or an **amount** of time spent total (such as it took 2 hours and 20 minutes to finish repairing customer x's cell phone).

If this represents the amount of time, how can I convert it to a normal hour/minute/second set of units?

Comment: Do you have one or two separate columns (you mention all entries start with a "midnight" value? if you have two you can use `TIMEDIFF('1970-01-01 00:05:46', '1970-01-01 00:00:00')` to get the time difference in a hh:mm:ss format

Comment: Most likely the former. I have never seen a date included in an amount of time spent.

Comment: @Pepper Sorry, I updated the description. They're not always  at 00:00:00, but in a hh:MM:ss format.

Comment: And you want to "extract" the hh:MM:ss part? if so `TIME('1970-01-01 hh:MM:ss')` should do it (sorry if i'm still not understanding how those dates represent an amount of time)

Answer (score 3):

I am just guessing here. It looks that your client side receives number of milliseconds that some process took to complete. However, your client erroneously (this is my guess) produces a Date from it. Since internally in java dates are stored as number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT. Your value '1970-01-01 00:05:46' was meant to be 5:46 (5 minutes and 46 seconds) meant as period of time or duration not tied to any particular date. But by mistake it was taken by client as a date that falls on 5:46 after ZERRO time (January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT). So (if I am correct) you need to fix the bug in your client and interpret your number of milliseconds as duration and not a date and then fix your old DB data that got produced by wrong logic

Comment: This is exactly what I was suspecting as well, thank you. Nothing else makes much sense.

Comment: No worries, you will get there

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql you use

```
Select SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:05:46'));
```

you get

> 05:46

So the time worked is 5 Minutes 46 Seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Moment versus Span-of-time

This apparently was an unfortunate design decision to take the data type for representing a moment, a specific point on the timeline,  (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in standard SQL) and abuse it to store a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.

## Retrieve a moment from database

Given the format of the example text, I suspect that data might actually be stored in a column of a date-time type. Double-check your statement about the column being `VARCHAR` (or if it is indeed `VARCHAR`, read all the way to end of this Answer).

Internally, that data type is likely to be storing the count of milliseconds or microseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC. So our goal is to get to that number.

Retrieve the pseudo-moment as a `OffsetDateTime` object using a JDBC 4.2 or later driver.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

If you only care about while seconds and don’t mise ignoring fractional second, call `toEpochSecond()`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = odt.toEpochSecond() ;
```

Pass that count to the `Duration` class. This class is for representing a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds plus fractional second.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( secondsSinceEpoch ) ;
```

You can then generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

For your example of 5 minutes and 46 seconds, that would be:

> PT5M46S

You can interrogate for the hours, minutes, and seconds parts.

```
long hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
long minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
```

… and so on.

If you care about sub-second detail, take your `OffsetDateTime` object and convert to the more basic type `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Then extract whole seconds and fractional seconds in nanoseconds.

```
long seconds = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
int nanos = instant.getNano() ;
```

Feed those to `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( seconds , nanos ) ;
```

## Retrieve text from database

If you are certain your original value is stored as text, well that would have been an even screwier design decision.

Manipulate to text to comply with ISO 8601 by repacking the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "1970-01-01 00:05:46".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` since we lack an indicator of time zone or offset from UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Apply an offset-from-UTC to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

From there, continue as discussed above.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I consider the `ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )` dangerous. The date-time strings may have been stored assuming a different time zone or offset (I believe the questioner is in Idaho, so US Mountain Time).

Answer (score 0):

> If this represents the amount of time, how can I convert it to a normal hour/minute/second set of units?

If you're doing this on the Java side rather than the MySQL side, you have a couple of options. Probably the simplest is to massage the string slightly so that it's appropriate to feed into [`Duration.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)), then use the various accessors on the `Duration` instance to get the values.